# Make something datalist-like in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, autosuggest, html-datalist

I’m currently making an app that has a textbox "clients" where the user can type in clients. And then the texbox makes him suggestions about previous clients.

I found that a `datalist` would be the best solution, but unfortunately, it seams that it is not yet supported by PhoneGap.

So is there something similar for PhoneGap? Where as while a user types something in a textbox and previous clients are suggested in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use autocomplete via Jquery in your phonegap.

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/